# PHP-How to Display Current Selected Value in Form field

Tags: php, mysql, html, sorting

hi i have set up a php based form submission method for sorting rows per page in a select drop down menu, it is working fine i get to sort the rows according to value selected, but my problem is when a **value** is selected for sort it doesn't shows up in form selected field as whats **currently selected**.

what i mean to say is that when a value is **selected** in drop down menu for sorting rows it should show up **as current** in select-box as **default value**, and if nothing is selected then **default row** value should show up **as current**.

please **see** here [here](http://download.cnet.com/windows/antivirus-software/?tag=rb_content;main) at the sorting method, it shows current(10) as default rows and when a value is selected it becomes as current on page reloads after querying database.

here is my **html code** for form field:

```
<form action="is-test.php" method="get">
<select name="rpp" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option selected value="">show</option><!-- i want default & current selected value here -->
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and **php code** for this sorting is:

```
$rowsperpage = '';
if (isset($_GET['rpp'])&& is_numeric($_GET['rpp'])) {
$rowsperpage = (int) mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['rpp']);
}else{
$rowsperpage='5';
}
```

and **mysql query** for this is:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tablename ORDER BY $orderby $sortby LIMIT $rowsperpage OFFSET $offset";
```

please sugest me a way to set selected value as current value.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<option>` tags, you should performed checking like this:

```
<option value="10" <?php if ($rowsperpage == 10) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>10</option>
<option value="20" <?php if ($rowsperpage == 20) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>20</option>
<option value="30" <?php if ($rowsperpage == 30) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>30</option>
```

So if you select `20`, it will displayed as the current value of the `<select>`

```
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20" selected="selected">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
```

To make things simpler, just use `for` loop like this:

```
for ($i = 10; $i <= 30; $i+= 10) {
  echo "<option value=\"$i\" ".($rowsperpage == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : '').">$i</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option selected value="<?php echo $rowsperpage; ?>"><?php echo $rowsperpage; ?></option>
```

A *possibly* better way to do this is with a loop:

```
for ($i = 10, $i <= 30; $i +=10) {
    $selected = ($i == $rowsperpage) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo sprintf('<option value="%d"%s>%d</option>', $i, $selected, $i);
}
```

Comment: i have tried like this but it shows one extra row in drop down menu with current value.